# asp.net side scrolling text

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

Is it possible to add a side scrolling text function to a label (or just any text) in asp.net? Had a look at the ajax control toolkit but could not find any extender for that.

Looking for the side scrolling effect you get at the bottom of the news channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML marquee tag. Place your label inside the tag.
Example:

```
 <marquee> 
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnything" Text="Hi This is me!"></asp:Label>
 </marquee>
```

Comment: Perfect. Something this simple is exactly what I need :)